# How to recreate the following signing cmd-line OpenSSL call using M2Crypto in Python?

Tags: python, openssl, x509, m2crypto

This works perfectly in command-line, I would like to do the same using M2Crypto in Python code.

```
openssl smime -binary -sign -signer certificate.pem -inkey key.pem \
                    -in some_file.txt -out signed_file -outform DER \
                    -passin pass:somepassword
```

Comment: You mean call this command inside python?

Comment: Maybe this site should helps you http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/doc/howto.smime.html

Comment: I mean to do the same what this cmd-line does but programmatically using M2Crypto. (I know I can use "call()" in Python but that's not what I want to do.

Comment: This link is very helpful thanks, however it's not clear how to save output file in DER format (examples only for SMIME messages in PEM format)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have been using M2Crypto to sign a file.

```
text = open('/path/to/some_file.txt').read()
passphrase = 'somepassword'
buffer = M2Crypto.BIO.MemoryBuffer(text)
signer = M2Crypto.SMIME.SMIME()
signer.load_key('/path/to/key.pem', '/path/to/certificate.pem', lambda x: passphrase)
p7 = signer.sign(buffer, flags=M2Crypto.SMIME.PKCS7_DETACHED)
out = M2Crypto.BIO.MemoryBuffer()
p7.write_der(out)
signature = out.getvalue()
print signature
```

This works well for me. You may need to play around with the flags in `signer.sign` if your signature is not exactly how you want it.