# Node.js equivalent to OpenSSL -sign operation

Tags: node.js, openssl, sign, smime

I'm trying to replicate the following operation in Node.js without spawning the OpenSSL command, bc that would require me to write files to disk. I already have the private key, the certificate and the file to be signed in memory, and I'm looking to get the signed file content as a buffer or string. I have been looking around but couldn't find anything suitable. Does anyone know about a proper solution? Thanks in advance!

```
openssl smime -sign -signer file.crt -inkey file.pem -in file.xml -out file.xml.cms -outform PEM -nodetach
```

Comment: Just for adding more details, I'm looking for something like this in Python using M2Crypto http://stackoverflow.com/a/12172540

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I ended up forking the smime package from NPM and applying the changes I needed, some IO is still involved: https://github.com/gastonelhordoy/smime/